# RestTemplate only get data I care about

Tags: spring, resttemplate

A RestTemplate request I am making gives a JSON request of a large data type. For example it responds with a channel object, a user object, and a preferences object.

I only need the information that relates to a channel object. Is there any way to have the responseType only deal with the channel object even though the response contains more than that?

I am only asking because I feel like it is pointless to create DTOs that contain fields that I don't care about and will never use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pojo with channel object and mark pojo to ignore unknown properties ,

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Myclass {
    Channel channel;
    ...
}
```

In rest template ,

```
   restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Myclass .class);
```